# Unbinding a lambda event handler

Tags: c++, c++11, wxwidgets

How can I unbind an event handler which I've bind as shown below?

```
MyFrame::MyFrame()
{
    Bind(wxEVT_COMMAND_MENU_SELECTED,
         [](wxCommandEvent&) {
            // Do something useful
         },

         wxID_EXIT);
}
```

Many thanks for the first answer. I've added some additional information.

The possibility to unbind an event handler by using a concrete Functor is documented and works fine, but if you use the C++ 11 lambda style to bind somthing, later there is no Functor availibale to call the unbind method. And this causes trouble if the corresponding `wxEvtHandler` should by destroied.

Is there a "trick". . . if not I don't see a real use case to bind by using lambda functors.
Hopefully I'm wrong . . .

Many thanks
Hacki

Comment: Possible duplicate of [wxWidgets: unbind event as its triggered](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18955287/wxwidgets-unbind-event-as-its-triggered)

Comment: @CamFerry, no it is not. Unbinding function takes event handler functor name and there is no name here with lambda. Its probably something in C++11...

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You can't unbind when the call to Bind has a lambda, as your example. If you store the lambda, then you can unbind from that, e.g.

```
class MyFrame 
{ 
    ... 
    std::function<void()> DoUnbind;
}

MyFrame::MyFrame()
{
    auto DoSomethingUseful = [](wxCommandEvent&) {
            // Do something useful
         };

    Bind(wxEVT_COMMAND_MENU_SELECTED,
         DoSomethingUseful,
         wxID_EXIT);

    DoUnbind = [DoSomethingUseful](){
        Unbind(wxEVT_COMMAND_MENU_SELECTED,
               DoSomethingUseful,
               wxID_EXIT);
    };
}
```

Comment: Why will that work? According to comments here you have to use the address of the functor to unbind. You captured by value, so `DoUnbind` has a fresh copy of the lambda which will not have the same address as the one that was originally bound.

Answer (score 3):

[wxWidget's documentation](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/3.1.0/classwx_evt_handler.html#a2b7df8272075a96daea78cdd799c00da) specifies the exact way `Unbind` works for functors (and lambdas as well):

> Currently functors are compared by their address which, unfortunately, doesn't work correctly if the same address is reused for two different functor objects.

So, if you want to `Unbind` some functor reliably, you should save the functor in a special place which is shared by `Bind` and `Unbind` call sites, and then pass the exact same object to both functions (they take [const-references](https://github.com/wxWidgets/wxWidgets/blob/d15bbcacd2c70f1fc3048d4f012dcbac7dd179cb/include/wx/event.h#L3553-L3559) despite documentation not reflecting it).

This applies both to lambdas and functors, so it's not even C++11-specific. If you want to `Unbind` something, this something should have a fixed address in memory. Consequently, it should have a name. That somewhat kills the beauty of lambdas.

So, this should work:

```
static auto event_handler = [](wxCommandEvent&) {
  // Do something
};
// ...
Bind(..., event_handler, ...);
// ...
Unbind(..., event_handler, ...);
```

But even this does not (or does, depending on your luck with location of temporary variables):

```
struct EventHandler {
  void operator()(wxCommandEvent&) const {
    // Do something
  }
};
// ...
Bind(..., EventHandler(), ...);
// ...
Unbind(..., EventHandler(), ...);
```

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately there is no way to do this currently, you will need to store your lambda in an object to give it an identity, e.g.

```
auto const handler = [](wxCommandEvent&) { ... };

// To bind it:
Bind(wxEVT_MENU, handler, wxID_EXIT);

// To unbind it:
Unbind(wxEVT_MENU, handler, wxID_EXIT);
```

Answer (score 0):

When the program finishes execution, all event handlers will be unbound from all controls. This is true even for lambdas.

It is very rare that you need to Unbind something inside the user code, but if you do the answer by @Caleth will work.